# Setting the exact location where the path connects to the node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

I have connected 2 nodes with a path:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw]{surname}{\mbox{Kennedy}} was killed in an assasin.

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) --++ (0,-1)  node [below, draw]{\footnotesize b. May 29, 1917, d. November 22, 1963, often referred to by his initials JFK, 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Because the path connects to the node's upper edge at the center by default, the left part of the node is out of the page. To make it right, I have tinkered with the `node` options like these:

```
node [below right=-10pt, draw]
node [below, right=-10pt, draw]
node [below, center=-10pt, draw]
```

None of them helped (I have tried different options for about an hour) I've searched that particular information  on the TikZ documentation, it wasn't of any help either.

How to set the exact location where the path connects to the node, so that the node would be at the desired location as given in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xshift` to move the node around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\tikzmarknode[inner sep=2pt,draw]{surname}{\mbox{Kennedy}} was killed in an assasin.

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,->](surname.south west) --++ (0,-1)  node [below, draw,anchor=north west,xshift=-3cm]{\footnotesize b. May 29, 1917, d. November 22, 1963, often referred to by his initials JFK, 35th president of the USA from 1961 to 1963};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]